# How to initialise Radaee Master or Classic for Android SDK with professional license

Tags: android, pdf

I have purchased a professional license for Radaee Android for my current Android project.

I have a license key and configured my Company Name, email and Android package name.

Whatever I try I cannot remove the Radaee Water Mark from any displayed PDF files.

I have tried using Radaee Classic v.3.65.1 and Master v1.2.1 SDK's.

My Android app gradle

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.pdf.application"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

The package name I registered for my license key i sthat of a sub module of my application and not the main App module package name. I've a feeling that is causing the issue.

However to investigate this idea I create a dummy app with the same package name as I registered for the license key and the Radaee watermark still appears.

How are you supposed to configure Radaee with a professional license for Android?

Comment: isn't this a question you should be asking their support ? not sure if you'll find an answer here, might be better (and faster) just to ask their support

Comment: @a_local_nobody, I've asked their support and they havent been very helpful... I was hoping someone in the SO community had experience with how to proceed